# Undefined index not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, image, uploading

Creating a small website that should show a few different tv shows. I have a page that should allow the user to enter a new tv programmes name and a picture of the tv programme.

For some reason im getting the undefined index error on lines: 41, 44, 45 and 52. Code is below:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Programme Title: <input type="text" name="title">   </br> 
    Select photo to upload:<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo">  <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);  --- ERROR line 41 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $title=$_POST['name']; --- ERROR line 44
 $pic=($_FILES['    ']['name']);  --- ERROR line 45


 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO programmes VALUES ('', '$title', '', '$pic')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))  --- ERROR line 52
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 

 ?>
```

Error msg:

> Undefined index: photo in C:\wamp\www\sky_coding\upload.php on line
>   45, 49 and 55 Undefined index: title in
>   C:\wamp\www\sky_coding\upload.php on line 48

Please help
im confused and not sure why im getting this error

any info will be helpful
thanks!

Comment: Please mark the lines.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju How do i mark the lines?

Comment: just write a line there like `error line` in comments

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: When you write a question about an error, __always__ include details of the error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.What are you trying to achieve with this line `$pic=($_FILES['    ']['name']);`

Comment: I added the error_reporting line but dont really see a difference also the empty brackets have been changed to ['photo']['name']

Comment: **" I added the error_reporting line but don't really see a difference "** What are the errors **SAYING**.

Comment: Undefined index: photo in C:\wamp\www\sky_coding\upload.php on line 45, 49 and 55 

Undefined index: title in C:\wamp\www\sky_coding\upload.php on line 48

Comment: What's the image size ? it may be over the allowed size.

Comment: Ive made the images really small. No larger than 50kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never bothered checking if a form was submitted, or a file was even uploaded. You just unconditionally execute the form-handling code.

At minimum you need something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   // form was submitted
   if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) {
         if ($_FILES['photo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
              ... file was successfully uploaded, process it
         } else {
              die("File upload failed with error " . $_FILES['photo']['error']);
         }
   }
   etc... etc... etc...
}
```

You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are also simply assuming that DB queries will never fail.

Comment: Yeah silly mistake on my part. That managed to get everything working

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `name` in post, but it should be `title` as provided in your form code

```
 $title=$_POST['title'];this should be title
```

Your are leaving the empty index, so add index as `photo`

```
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); you have not added any index here.
```

Comment: That stills gives the undefined index error for "photo" and "title"

Comment: Can you please summarize what you quoting? This violates stackoverflow posting guidelines.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean?

Comment: I added the Isseet function for the submit button and the errors have gone. The images are uploading but once i hit the upload button it says  Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\wamp\www\sky_coding\upload.php on line 59

Comment: replace `uploadedfile ` with `photo`.